# How to filter histories of current branch and the master in source tree UI?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

In source tree, I could see either the histories of all branches / the current branch.
However , Is there a way to view only the master(merges from other branch) and the current branch.
Because I don't want to see the details of other check-ins happening
in other branches.   Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SourceTree, the commit history can only be filtered by **current branch** or **all branches**. You can not filter the commit history for current branch and `master` branch.

That mean, you can only view the commit history for current branch or all branches.

And if you want to view part of branches' commit history, you can view in terminal. To view the commit history for current branch and `master` branch, you can execute the command:

```
git log master <current branch name> --graph --decorate --oneline
```